# How to set memcache as CacheModule store in nestJs?

Tags: nestjs

GET request are being cached but only in memory store, nothing in memcache.

Module setting -

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        CacheModule.register({
            isGlobal: true,
            ttl: 10,
            options: {
                hosts: ["localhost:11211"],
            },
            store: memcachedStore,
            driver: Memcache,
        }),
```

Controller setting -

```
    @ApiBearerAuth()
    @UseInterceptors(MyCustomeCacheInterceptor)
    @Get()
    async subscriptionOverviewGet(@Req() request: any): Promise<any> {
      ......
    }
```

Tested memcache by running - **stats items** in its console, but nothing related to the request ( though they are definitely cached somewhere, guessing in the default memory store)

Has anyone managed to store GET request in memcache using CacheModule?

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of debug, I found the issue, sharing for others that may fall here. The problem was in how I imported the services from the libraries.

Bad code:

```
import memcachedStore from "cache-manager-memcached-store";
import Memcache from "memcache-pp";
```

Good code:

```
import * as memcachedStore from "cache-manager-memcached-store";
import * as Memcache from "memcache-pp";
```